# image.html.twig naming sugestions

Tags: theming, media

I need to customize the *image.html.twig* template. I have a new content type with an image field (*field_tile_image*).
How can I overwrite the default image template only for one block?

I tried different naming but it's still using *image.html.twig*. There aren't other name suggestions.

Comment: What kind of modifications do you want to apply? The thing is, it will be hard to do what you want. You'll probably want to add a different viewmode for your image. To do so, you'll need to work with media instead of the basic image field.

Comment: @JFK I need to remove image width, height attributes also add custom HTML tags, but only for this image field without touching the original one.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about changing the template file used from an image field, but only for a block, the question should make clearer the relation between the content type and the block, how that block is created, and what exactly it outputs. At least there should be more information that allow to "identify" that block.

Answer (score 1):

The image.html.twig file does not have any names suggestions by default. Then you have to add it yourself. You can do it using [hook_theme_suggestions_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x).

Also, here's an example of this hook usage:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
 */
function MY_THEME_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'taxonomy_term') {
    $term = $variables["elements"]["#taxonomy_term"];
    $vid = $term->get('vid')->target_id;
    $view_mode = $variables["elements"]["#view_mode"];
    
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $view_mode;
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $vid . '__' . $view_mode;
  }
}
```

You can read more about it here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/working-with-twig-templates 
and here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions